# AdMob Ads not are not show after adding permission to my manifest

Tags: android, admob

I test the app were the add should be there was a box that said add the activity to my manifest and as soon as I add the now there is nothing down there were that box was. here's all the code ive put in my app I realized some is useless now because of all the different things ive tried my app is knee deep in unneeded code if you see some I can delete let my know as well please.

Main question Why are the ads not appearing

JAVA

```
AdView myAdView;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game_play);  


        myAdView=(AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
        adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
        myAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

main layout

```
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/android_drinking"     
    tools:context=".PlayerInput" >


    <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            ads:adUnitId="a14ff402be4457c"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

attrs xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="com.admob.android.ads.AdView">
<attr name="backgroundColor" format="color" />
<attr name="primaryTextColor" format="color" />
<attr name="secondaryTextColor" format="color" />
<attr name="keywords" format="string" />
<attr name="refreshInterval" format="integer" />
</declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

android Manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<meta-data android:value="YOUR_ID_HERE" android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID" />
<!-- AdMobActivity definition -->
<activity android:name="com.admob.android.ads.AdMobActivity"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden" />
<!-- Track Market installs -->
<receiver android:name="com.admob.android.ads.analytics.InstallReceiver"
android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>

 <activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

  </manifest>
```

link to the [tutorial](http://jimmod.com/blog/2012/07/jimmys-blog-adding-admobs-ads-to-android-application/) that i'm trying tonight.

Answer (score 0):

the adds function I emailed the app to myself installed it on my wifes tablet and they work must I be setting it to test wrong I removed the java part from the app as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple Tutorial with all needed info

[**How to add Google ads in Android apps (Google Admob Ads**](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/06/how-to-add-google-ads-in-android-apps.html))

Please Keep in Mind while developing this app

1. You need Google Advertisement Publisher ID.
2. You need to add  Google AdMob Ads SDK.jar file in your class path
3. you must have app target is API 13 or newer
4. Also PL don't forget to add internet permission
5. you need to add Google ads activity in Manifest file in application tag, this way

   ```
   <activity  
               android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"  
               android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />  
       </application>
   ```

Hope it helps you!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check into LogCat if you are correctly making requests to admob?

Some times the only problem is that the request fails for poor admob inventory.